AG Charts Stacked Bar Chart: Handling Large Value Ranges in React
I'm using AG Charts in React to create a stacked bar chart with values ranging from hundreds of thousands to several billions. The smaller values (e.g., 100,000 or 900,000) become nearly invisible when plotted alongside larger values in the billions.
I've tried using a logarithmic scale, but the distribution isn't satisfactory—the chart still doesn't effectively display the smaller values. Here's a simplified version of my chart configuration:
<AgChartsReact
  options={{
    data: myData,
    series: [
      {
        type: 'bar',
        xKey: 'category',
        yKeys: ['smallValue', 'largeValue'],
        stacked: true,
      },
    ],
    yAxis: {
      type: 'number', // Tried 'log' here
    },
  }}
/>

Is there a mathematical formula or method to set an optimal maximum value for the y-axis to improve visibility? Alternatively, is there a better scaling approach to handle such a wide range of values in a stacked bar chart?
Any suggestions would be appreciated!
Number type

Log type

